# Declaring multiple type in typescript as string and Array

Tags: typescript

I am a beginner in typescript. I am declaring a variable as multiple types.

```
export class Message {
     c: string|ArrayBuffer|Array<any>
...
}
```

When I try to invoke forEach function, getting an error.

```
message.c.forEach ( each->{})
```

Error Message:

```
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | any[] | ArrayBuffer'.
  Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Can someone suggest how to resolve this issue? thank you.

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. Strings do not have a `forEach` method, so trying to do so throws a compile error

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted. It is a multi type string or array. Array has forEach right so I am not expecting this error.

Comment: What do you expect to happen by running non-existent function "forEach" on string or ArrayBuffer?

Comment: or Array<any>; so forEach is with Array right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [union type documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.

Neither *string* nor *ArrayBuffer* has `forEach` method.

Do a runtime type check of a variable and call `forEach` only if it has `Array` type:

```
let { c } = message;

if (c instanceof Array) {
    c.forEach((value, index, array) => {});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. not sure if you have missed to see Array as it datatype in addition to ArrayBuffer.  As forEach is a member of Array it should not show me compilation error correct? Pl correct if my understanding is wrong. thanks

Comment: @javapedia.net *Every* type must contain `forEach`, not just one. If you use a union type, you can only access members that are common for every type in a union. You can read documentation for union types in typescript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: Thanks. Will check. I implement based on your answer and mark it as answer later today